# Is there a way to get to the splintered world in Hyrule Warriors: Age of Calamity?

Tags: hyrule-warriors-age-of-calamity

When i'm playing Hyrule Warriors: Age of Calamity, the game talks about

> a splintered world the little robot made when traveling to the past to help stop the calamity.

Is there a way to access that world or is it just not available to access in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to access the splintered world.

There might be plans to add it with future DLC content, but that would be pure speculation.